# How to install IBM Ricoh Infoprint drivers on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation

How can one successfully install the PostScript 3 drivers for those IBM Ricoh InfoPrint models: 1572, 1812, 1832 1852 on Windows 7 ?

One year ago, I could install the Windows 7 64-bit drivers for the InfoPrint 1832 / 1852 models by downloading the drivers from this link: 
https://support.rpp.ricoh-usa.com/internet/dcfdata.nsf/vwWeb/P4000975

But it seems impossible to add the drivers for the InfoPrint 1572 and 1812 on the same computer. I tried the InfoPrint PCL/PostScript Universal Drivers Version 1.6.2 : https://www.infoprintsolutionscompany.com/internet/dcfdata.nsf/vwWeb/P4000927
as well as the dedicated driver for the Infoprint 1812 model, which was written for previous versions of Windows.
None works.

The InfoPrint 1812 printer is detected, but display with an exclamation mark icon on a yellow triangle. When trying adding a new printer, the Infoprint 1812 does not display in the list of printers for the Infoprint brand, where the 1832 and 1852 models are already listed.
The same with the InfoPrint 1572 printer.

I encounter the same kind of issue when trying to add the drivers for the 1832/1852 models where the Infoprint 1812 is installed.

Restarting the computer doesn't change anything.

The place where I can connect the printer is without Internet, so that I have to install the drivers offline.

Comment: I observe that on one of my computers running Windows 7 64-bit, I have a generic driver named "IBM Infoprint 1000 Series PS3" and I tested it as working with all these Infoprint models : 1572, 1812, 1832, 1852. However, I cannot remember where I had downloaded it, if from an official site (Infoprint / Ricoh / IBM) or elsewhere. Usually, I try avoiding non official driver sources.